# How to read in binary mode and transfer the information to new file

Tags: c++

i tried to open and read an application in binary mode and get 100 characters(For a large file, i did this so that i could read all the characters) in binary mode and then transfer them to new file(in fact, this program will be the same as the previous program, but with a different name ) to find out if it works properly or not
so anyway my source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Vector of 100 characters initialised to 0
    vector<char> ch(100, 0);
    ifstream  file("example.exe",ios::in|ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
    
        while (file)
        {
            file.read(ch.data(), 100);
            // Get the number of bytes actually read
            size_t count = file.gcount();
            ch[file.gcount()] = '\0';
            //cout << ch.data() << endl;
            ofstream output("output.exe", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
            output.write(ch.data(), sizeof(100));
            output.close();

        }
    }
    file.close();   
}
```

my problem is the output with the correct information is not included and the size is smaller than the original application(example.exe) what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `output.write(ch.data(), sizeof(100));`
should be replaced with `output.write(ch.data(), count);`
Since `sizeof(100)` only returns 4, which is the size in bytes of an integer.

You should also remove the line `ch[file.gcount()] = '\0';` since `file.gcount()` might be out of bound.

I just tested it and this works for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<char> ch(100, 0);
    ifstream file("app.exe",ios::in|ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        ofstream output("app_copy.exe", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
        while (file)
        {
            file.read(ch.data(), 100);
            output.write(ch.data(), file.gcount());
        }
        output.close();
    }
    file.close();   
}
```

Notice that `ios::app` is replaced by `ios::trunc`, which will delete the content of the file when opening.

Comment: yes it fixed some problems and still the size of program is smaller than original and I can't run it

Comment: now its working for one application properly and have another application that still doesn't work and I don't know why it seems some data is missing

Comment: So it works for one app and doesn't for another app? How is the copy of the second app now (size, is it executable?)

Comment: it working for app that I maked in visual but for other apps the size is different a little (about 30-40 kb) less than original as u said I replaced and delete and one app is not executable and other has error